# image on table <TD>

Tags: html

html code to make image size are same with table size.
bacause i want to create a newsletter..
and how to set table size in html

Comment: I dont get it, whats your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your stylesheet

```
td img{
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%
}
```

Comment: although i dont really recommend using tables for layouts, you should really do that with divs

Comment: i'm not using stylesheet..just one html page for nesletter

Comment: Unfortunately, you usually have to use tables in HTML newsletters for any sort of cross compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

You set table size using width and height attributes.

`<table style="width:200px;height:100px;">`

Obviously, you can do that with a CSS class as well.